# Длительность сессии по умолчанию для tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, сессия, timeout

Каков тайм-аут сеанса по умолчанию для веб-приложений, развернутых на `tomcat`? Является ли это специфичным для браузера? В моем веб-приложении тайм-аут по умолчанию не упоминается ни в `web.xml`, ни в коде.

---

<sup>Свободный перевод вопроса [«Default session timeout for Apache Tomcat applications»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14433070/11141611) от участника [@einfotechie](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/567089/infotechie).</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываем файл `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` и находим следующее:

```xml
<!-- ==================== Default Session Configuration ================= -->
<!-- You can set the default session timeout (in minutes) for all newly   -->
<!-- created sessions by modifying the value below.                       -->

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

т.е. значение по умолчанию для сессии - **30 минут**. Это значение можно переопределить отдельно для каждого приложения, либо целиком для всего сервера.

---

<sup>При формировании ответа использовался [ответ на вопрос «Default session timeout for Apache Tomcat applications»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14433076/11141611) от участника [@evgeniy-dorofeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831293/evgeniy-dorofeev).</sup>